# Object is broken in Smooth Mesh Preview (press 3) maya 2014

Tags: 3d, maya, modeling

[image]

Model after "Mesh > Mirror Geometry"

[image]

Model I created (right) and Model on my video tutorial in Smooth Mesh Preview

I encounter the following issues when moving through mode "Smooth Mesh Preview" object is broken. Help me fix this! Thanks

Comment: 3D Questions are no longer in scope on our website through community consensus. There is a proposal for a 3D StackExchange site that could use your support: [3D Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics)

Comment: @Luciano do you have a meta link to support your comment?

Comment: @Ryan There's plenty of discussions, including http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/whats-the-census-on-cad-and-3d-for-gd-se/2866#2866  and http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2723/why-is-this-site-called-graphic-design-when-it-doesnt-include-3d-questions and maybe we should update these templates http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2473/a-list-of-snippets-for-commenting

Answer (score 0):

The center ring of edges is not connected, just overlapping. You need to merge them together correctly first.

- While in smooth mesh preview mode, select the three polygons on each side of the problem area. Press *delete* to remove them. At this point it may appear fixed, but the two halves are not quite joined yet.
- Select the vertices (what looks like 12, but is actually 24) and select *Edit Mesh > Merge Vertices*. This will turn the 24 vertices into truly 12.

Two views that may help are: the Poly Count heads up display, and the Highlight Geometry Borders polygon display. Poly Count will show you how many vertices you have selected, and if it's more than you expect you may need to merge them together. Highlight Geometry Borders will draw wireframes thicker at edges that haven't been merged.

Comment: thanks for your help by "Edit Mesh > Merge " but it's not really helpful because there is distortion overlaps. I'm learning tutorials www.digitaltutors.com, models generated by a half after creating model and use tools "Mesh > Mirror Geometry"  and the model was broken in point symmetry in mode Smooth Mesh Preview. This does not happen in video tutorials. I think that may be because a certain set incorrectly?